# Actionscript 3: Changing frame in main timeline from package?

Tags: actionscript-3, package, mouseevent, frame, movieclip

I have a class called "airport" which extends movieclip. I have, successfully, managed to add a mouseclick-eventlistener for every object of the class that i create.

When I click on one of the objects, I am supposed to enter frame 2 on the main timeline.

I've tried to use the following code inside the class:

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

private function clickHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        MovieClip(parent).nextFrame();
    }
```

When I click on one of the objects, I don't enter frame 2, but the whole screen goes blank. Any ideas? Thanks for advice.

PS: If you request more of my code to provide an answer, I would be happy to provide it.

Comment: is airport the class name you exported it as? in which case you would just do `gotoAndPlay( currentFrame + 1 )`

Comment: That also shows up a blank page when clicking on one of the objects..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh..I just found the error. In my code I used the line

```
this.parent.visible = false
```

to hide the objects when I entered next frame.

What I did not know was that this also would hide every other movieclip, which results in the screen beeing totally white.

Comment: Haha those are the worst bugs. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever 'this' is isn't a direct child of the main timeline. Try this:

```
private function clickHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    MovieClip(root).nextFrame();
}
```

Comment: I've tried that aswell, but replacing "root" with "parent" gives exactly the same result - blank page.